# What type of hazelnut is this?

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees, nut-trees

Can anyone tell me what type of hazelnut is this? Apparently it's resistant to drought and it's likely to be an Italian one. I searched online and it's similar looking to one type, but don't want to prejudge any opinions here.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: good well illustrated question , maybe include approximate size could assist identification